# Doxygen documentation

Tags: cmake, doxygen

I recently started using doxygen with clion. I made doxygen create all the htlm files while code compiling using this in the CMAKELIST:

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    set(BUILD_DOC_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/docs/output")
    if(NOT EXISTS "${BUILD_DOC_DIR}")
        file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${BUILD_DOC_DIR}")
    endif()

    set(DOXYGEN_IN "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/docs/Doxyfile")
    set(DOXYGEN_OUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile")
    configure_file("${DOXYGEN_IN}" "${DOXYGEN_OUT}" @ONLY)

    message("Doxygen build started")
    add_custom_target(Doxygen ALL
            COMMAND "${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}" "${DOXYGEN_OUT}"
            WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
            COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
            VERBATIM)
else(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    message("Doxygen needs to be installed to generate the documentation.")
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

But while i compile the code, doxygen not only created a htlm for my own functions as it actually creates a documentation for every function from clion. Is there a way to make it only create that htlm file for my own coded functions?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What do you mean by " it actually creates a documentation for every function from clion", can you give some examples?

Comment: Maybe you should dive into Doxygen manual and edit manually the doxyfile, it will be much clearer to you.
Side comment: when I see this, I'm glad I stayed away from Cmake, and sticked to gnumake only!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may simply exclude some file patterns from being processed by doxygen:

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
....
set(DOXYGEN_EXCLUDE_PATTERNS */folder_with_clion/* */other_folder/*)
...
endif()
```